# reading /dev/ttyHS from seperate thread has lot of delay

Tags: android, multithreading, terminal

I am trying to implement native Android APIs to communicate over UART.

This is the mechanism I am using:

in `Main_process`:

1. Open the terminal
2. Create `thread1`
3. `while(1) {  Terminal_write("Test", 4);  }`

in `thread1`:

1. change the file status flag to read in block mode,
2. `read(fd, buf, Max_Len`);

Ths issue here is that the read operation in `thread1` is too slow, and the data appears on my device many seconds after I enter the data from PC's terminal.

Comment: OP you might want to read about [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: How about putting some pacing or sane rate limiting in that write loop?  Also make sure your terminal on the PC isn't stuck in line mode and not sending anything until a newline character (possible overridden by some delay or random event)